# Kurento - Blurness in the Remote stream stored images

Tags: opencv, video, webrtc, kurento

**What I did:**

I am using **Kurento Media Server** to store the video streaming frames in the server. I can store the frames in the server by using opencv-plugin sample.

I am storing the video frames in the below two scenarios.

> 1) I need to take the images when the user show their faces in front of
>   the camera.(Note: No movements)
>
> Issues: No issue. I can get the quality images.
>
> 2) I need to take the images when the user walks in a room.(Note: The
>   user is moving)
>
> Issues: Most of the stored images are blurred in the server when they
>   are in moving (while walking).

**What I want:**

i) Is this the default behavior of the KMS (gstreamer)?

> Note: I can see the local stream videos clearly in the browser while moving. But
>   the remote stream videos only got blurred while moving.

ii) Did anyone face this issue before. If yes, how do I solve this issue?

iii) Do I want to change any gstreamer configuration?

iv) Anyone give me a suggestion to overcome this issue?

Comment: Did you try changing the quality of the image sent by the media server?

Comment: I have changed the constraints and got the clear images in the scenario #1. But In the scenario #2, I got blur after changed the constrains when the user moves. Can you please check the below images. (1) clear image - https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/140263/1947556/BRiRz8ptSYdAdyG/frame_000169.jpg (2) Blur image - https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/140263/1947556/g5vBi35sx2v02O2/frame_000193.jpg

Comment: Did you try without your filter? Just create a regular loopback in webrtc, and check what the server is sending you back. Also, what version og KMS are you using?

Comment: I am trying with my opencv-filter. KMS version is 6.4.0. I did check in the hello world sample. I didn't get that blur in the remote stream video. But I didn't save the images without filter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that the exposition time of your camera is high. It's like taking a picture of a car with low light.

When there is movement in the image, getting a simple frame, specially if the camera exposition time is long (due to low light conditions of low camera quality), will end in this kind of images.

On continuous video you don't notice this blurriness because there is a sequence of images, and your brain fills the gaps.

**Edit**

You can try to improve the quality that you are sending to the server by changing constrains on `WebRTCEndpoint` using properties [`setMaxVideoSendBandwidth`](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/_static/langdoc/javadoc/org/kurento/client/BaseRtpEndpoint.html#setMaxVideoSendBandwidth(int)) and [`setMaxVideoRecvBandwidth`](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/_static/langdoc/javadoc/org/kurento/client/SdpEndpoint.html#setMaxVideoRecvBandwidth(int)). As long as there is available bandwidth you'll get a better quality.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can understand your point. But  the local streaming not getting blurred. only the remote streaming getting blurred. Can you please check the below video - http://d.pr/v/1aQEK . I have tried with 4 different resolution cameras(0.3MP, 1MP, 5MP, 8MP). I am getting the same result in all cameras.

Comment: ok. I did change the constraints as below in kurento-client.js file.
var params = {maxVideoSendBandwidth: 1000} and var params = { maxVideoRecvBandwidth: 1000}; But it is not reflecting in the local/remote video streams. I did add the console logs. But the logs are not printing in the console. whether the above steps are correct?

Comment: I mean in kurento media server WebRTCEndpoint, not in browser PeerConnection

Comment: Do you mean /etc/kurento/modules/kurento/WebRTCEndpoint.conf.ini?

Comment: No, I mean the point in your source code where you create the `WebRtcEndpoint` using `KurentoClient`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109701/discussion-between-karthi-and-santoscadenas).